# Cordova App - Access of database made in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using this plugin for database. https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

Now in android, I have made database through android studio which I want to access through cordova.

Is it possible?

I just want to fetch data through cordova. Data insertion is done by android.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage, you have two options:

1.- Using https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext ( is other version of the plugin ). You need a **database.db**.

2.- Using the function **sqlBatch** of same plugin. for pre-populated database.